# How to setup base url in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, url, configuration, zend-framework2

In my application there I need to send mail, which contains my application's link, so that user will click the link and navigate to the application directly.

I want to use something in global configuration so that, for development and production I only need to change the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put file in global config directory

```
return array(
    'url' => 'your_url'
);
```

And then

```
$config = new Zend\Config\Config(include 'config/yourConfig.php');
$config->url;
```

Comment: is there any other way `include 'config/yourConfig.php'` ?  coz its not working

Comment: Well, this should be path to your custom config file (in this case, from zend root into `config` directory and into `yourConfig.php` file). What problem exactly do you have?